# Dict in Django TemplateView throws Server Error 500, Suggested to use ListView that helps for DetailView

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-views, django-templates

I'm attempting to utilise the dictionary **prices** to retrieve the stock prices from yahoo finance. And the Django database is where I get my stock tickers. In HTML, I am unable to utilise dict. Please review the code samples I've included below.

If the datatype for the variable "prices" is likewise a dict, Django produces a 500 server error. I need to pull stock prices from yahoo finance and show stock tickers from the Django database in HTML. How can I fix it?

Please give me some advice on how to show my coins using ListView. In order to assist me with DetailView, which is crucial to my online application.

I want to say thank you.

**Model:**

```
class Coin(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker
```

**View:**

```
class BucketView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'coinbucket/bucket.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        symbols = [symbol.ticker for symbol in Coin.objects.all()]

        prices = {}
        for symbol in symbols:
            ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol)
            price = ticker.history(period='1d')['Close'][0]
            prices[symbol] = f'$ {price:.6f}'

        context["prices"] = prices
        return context
```

**Template:**

```
{% for coin in coins %}
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 my-2">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">{{ coin }}</div>
                    <div class="col">{{ prices[coin] }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Values of dict **prices**:

```
{'BTC-USD': '$ 29335.927734', 'ETH-USD': '$ 1987.428223', 'XRP-USD': '$ 0.498745', 'DOGE-USD': '$ 0.090749', 'LTC-USD': '$ 94.516197'}
```

Following code snippets are tried, but no results:

```
<div class="col">{{ prices['coin'] }}</div>
```

```
<div class="col">{{ prices.coin }}</div>
```

```
<div class="col">{{ prices.get(coin, 'N/A') }}</div>
```

Comment: Share the stacktrace to get more insights about the error. Since template normally does not produce a 500 error. Share also the actual prices dict so we can see whats inside.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot access a dictionary like this in django-template-language

```
<div class="col">{{ prices[coin] }}</div>
```

**try this**

```
<div class="col">{{ prices.coin }}</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your work! However, I tried your method, and it was unsuccessful. Please take a closer look at the issue.